# Usage of com.google.android.things library

Tags: java, android

I need to use a package in my Android-Java project:

```
import com.google.android.things.device.*;
```

But, there exists a compilation time exception. I guess Android SDK does not have the package, and I think a dependency configuration must be set in Gradle. That is why, I have written following statement to "dependencies" section of module`s Gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.things:device:1.0'
```

Then, I had Gradle synchronized by Android Studio. However, the project does not still import the package. Probably, "repositories" section should be applied by Gradle in order to fetch the library from remote computer. I reseached [official Android documentation;](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/device/package-summary)
nevertheless, I was able to find neither a maven URL nor an instruction to include the package. In addition, [Google Maven Repository](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html) does not have com.google.android.things.device entry. How can I exploit the package via my project?

Comment: Can you try this [library](https://github.com/dybarsky/android-things-demo/blob/master/build.gradle)? ```implementation 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0'```

Comment: Correct! I wish online Android documentation told necessity of "androidthings" artifact so as to use com.google.android.things.device package.

Comment: @STEEL did you managed to run it because I have to many problems to run this lib. I believe that google has replace the implementation with stub methods

Answer (score 0):

`com.google.android.things.device` is a package of **com.google.android.things** as you can see in [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/packages). Knowing this you can find the implementation code in [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.things/androidthings/1.0) or in [Google's Maven Repository](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=things#com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0) by simply searching for the library name which would be **com.google.android.things**.

The implementation `com.google.android.things:device:1.0'` does not exist.